# How to delete S3 key in nested folder?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a bucket with many subfolders. They are designed like this:

`bucket_name/nginx_archives/server_name/server_name_date_time.tar.gz`

However, all the oldest files are `.csv`, and I need to remove them.

I can see the keys with:

```
servers = ['server1', 'server2', 'server3', 'server4', etc, etc]

for server in servers:
   for object in the_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='nginx_archives/'+server+'/'):
       key = object.key
       if key.endswith('.csv'):
           print(key)
```

It gives me output like this:

```
nginx_archives/server1/empty.csv
nginx_archives/server2/empty.csv
nginx_archives/server3/empty.csv
nginx_archives/server4/empty.csv
nginx_archives/server5/empty.csv
```

`key.delete()` does not work. How can I delete these keys without manually going through every single folder? There are about 50.

Trying to use `key.delete()` gives me:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'delete'`

Comment: Use `object.delete()` rather than `key.delete()`. The latter is just a Python string.

Comment: Oh, that's just lovely. object.delete() just deleted all of my nested folders.

Comment: @DevOpsSauce S3 does not actually have folders, it's a flat object store so if you remove all objects that share a common prefix, the "folder" (as displayed in UIs) will disappear.

Comment: Your code simply deleted the objects whose keys ended in `.csv`, one by one. If no folders appear afterwards, then it's because they never actually existed. They were logically present (inferred from the keys of existing objects) but not actually present. This is typical for object stores.

Comment: I'm just wanting to rotate old keys by deleting the oldest, but only the files, not the "folders." I know they're not actually folders btw. :)

Comment: It's generally better not to have them, but if you must then you can either create placeholder objects at a suitable key (e.g. `nginx_archives/server1/ignore.me`) or create a zero-sized object whose key is the folder that you want e.g. `nginx_archives/server1/`.

Answer (score 0):

So the result of "object.key" returns a string value for the key not a boto3 object.  That's why you're getting the error.  You just need to modify your code to create a new boto3 object and run delete.  Something like this with your bucket name and the boto3 s3 resource.

```
servers = ['server1', 'server2', 'server3', 'server4', etc, etc]

for server in servers:
   for s3_object in the_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='nginx_archives/'+server+'/'):
       key = s3_object.key
       if key.endswith('.csv'):
           s3_object.delete()
```

Comment: No need to do that. The objects collection on the bucket is already an iterable of [ObjectSummary](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#objectsummary) resources and you can call delete on those directly.

Comment: Good call out.  I'll update.